# Reverse the synonym of indicator-power tag to indicator and rename it to power-indicator

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Today I killed the battery-indicator tag. Why, well, because I know there's a tag that already covers that topic, [indicator-power] but checking out several questions I knew why the user that created the tag did, it's confusing and he's not finding the proper tag! People will look for power/battery indicator because that's how they are called, so we need that tag. Can this be reverted back?

Comment: I agree with you; power-indicator makes more sense. It appears several of the indicator tags are written this way. Is there a benefit to doing it in reverse or something?